# Drawing problems with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this code in a function which is called from `$(document).ready`. The problem is that in my web you see the axis, but bars are not show. I don´t know what the problem is:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    axisY: {
        title: "percent",
        gridThickness: 0
    },
    legend: {
        visible: false,
    },
    toolTip: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    animationEnabled: true,
    data: [],
});
var data = [];
percentGraph.forEach(function(el, i) {
    var objeto1 = {
        type: "stackedBar100",
        showInLegend: false,
        name: el.code,
        dataPoints: []
    }
    el.percents.forEach(function(el2, j) {
        if (i === j) {
            var objeto2 = {
                y: el2.percent,
                label: el2.name,
                color: colores[el2.code]
            }
        } else {
            var objeto2 = {
                y: el2.percent,
                label: el2.name,
                color: 'white'
            }
        }
        objeto1.dataPoints.push(objeto2);
    });
    data.push(objeto1);
});
chart.options.data = data;
chart.render();
```

with `console.log(chart.options.data)` I have this result:

```
dataPoints: Array[4]
0: Object
color: "white"
label: "Direccion "
x: 0
y: "10"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
color: "white"
label: "Talento"
x: 1
y: "60"
__proto__: Object
2: Object
color: "white"
label: "Ingenieria"
x: 2
y: "15"
__proto__: Object
3: Object
color: "rgb(45,204,205)"
label: "Ingenieria"
x: 3
y: "15"
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
name: "04"
showInLegend: false
type: "stackedBar100"
```

this is the data strcuture for each `chart.options.data` object

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found that problem is thtat el2.percent was a string and canvasjs needs a number.